# How to get Yammer Praise feed using Yammer API?

Tags: office365, yammer

Is there any way to get only Praised feed of Yammer using Yammer API?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a supported API for this at this time. I can follow up with our product team @ Yammer if there is any plans to include this in the future.